# About the usage of "am to-uri"

Tags: android, adb

About the usage of "am to-uri"

It seems related to contentProvider?

In the am help, I couldn't understand the commend of "am to-uri", What is it for?

Answer (score 0):

`am to-uri <parameters>` command is just for converting the `<parameters>` to the Intent URI format. It creates the intent out of provided `<parameters>` and then just prints out the result of the intent's `.toUri()` method without actually sending it out.